# Device does not boot after crash without power plug

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, boot, crashes

In the last few weeks I'm faced with a somehow strange behaviour of my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S4 Active, GT-I9295, Android 4.2.2, Kernel-Version 3.4.0-2015525):

If the phone crashes resulting in power-off when doing some CPU or network intensive task, it is not possible to boot it afterwards unless it is plugged into the power outlet. Even using a so called Battery Power pack as external power supply doesn't help.

In some cases, it boots until the PIN input. In other cases, it completely refuses to boot.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: the reason was a defect in the battery. There was a small crack over the side of the battery. It was replaced by the shop where I bought the Phone last year.